# How to add this effect (grains) in Photoshop and Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, noise

[image]

This doesn't seem to a normal noise. Is it created by a brush in Illustrator?

My original question is: How to create this effect in Photoshop and Illustrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same effect as @user287001 suggests, but more dynamic.

- Create a *Solid Color* layer for the background color.
- Create a *Solid Color* layer for the noise.
- Select the *Layer Mask* of the noise layer and fill it with black.
- In the *Properties* panel set the *Feather* of the noise layer mask to a relatively high number.
- Set the *Blend Mode* of the noise layer to *Dissolve*.
- Use the *Pencil Tool* to paint with white on the noise layer mask.
- Select the noise layer, right click it and convert it to a *Smart Object*.
- Set the *Blend Mode* of the new *Smart Object* to *Normal*.
- Add a *Gaussian Blur* filter to the *Smart Object*.

[image]

Now you can dynamically change the background color and the blur applied. Inside the smart object you can change the color, transparency (with dissolve it's the frequency of pixels) and the feather of the noise.

Comment: How did you create these *Solid Layers*?

Comment: Same button where you create *Adjustment Layers*. In the top of the menu. You can also just fill an ordinary layer, but the nice thing with *Solid Color* layers is the possibility to change the color later.

Comment: Oh. I often use it just skipped from my mind.

Comment: Okay it works. Can you tell why you used Pencil tool and a Mask feather option instead of just using a soft brush tool? Soft brush would be easy as there are less steps.

Further, why did you change the blend mode to Normal of smart object? Dissolve and Normal didn't have any effect for this project.

Comment: I use pencil with mask feathering because it makes the feathering dynamic. I like that, but brush with the same feathering will give same result. About changing the blend mode. It's almost a bug in PS. It keeps the dissolve blend mode on the smart layer even though there is also dissolve on the layer inside the smart object. So if you don't change the blend mode back to normal the blur effect won't be anti-aliased but also dissolved. Try and see the difference.

Comment: If I don't accept your answer would you consider it rude?

Comment: It's totally up to you. Accept the answer you think is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Oh wait. This is only half answer ;)

Comment: The answer to the other half is: I wouldn't make this in Illustrator.  (But it might be possible using gradients with grain effect.)

Answer (score 1):

Paint in Photoshop to a new layer with a big soft brush which has blending mode Dissolve (the blending mode of the brush, layer has mode=Normal). Airbrush mode =ON or reduced brush opacity help to control the coverage.

After painting blur and reduce the layer opacity:

[image]

In the left there's some painting. In the middle Gaussian blur is applied and in the right layer opacity is reduced.

Effects like this are wasteful in Illustrator except as raster image imports, because thousands of objects are needed. SVG effects can make it, but finally they must be rasterized,too, because many common exports do not support SVG effects.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the details about Illustrator :)

Comment: Shall I accept it?

Comment: Accept only the most useful answer. Accept nothing if there's nothing you see useful enough. If All answers are somehow off the point you can augment the question for ex, by starting " Seemingly my question is unclear. I must add that...."

Comment: I wanna accept Wolff's answer because that also taught some more things. But I don't wanna make you feel bad because of this.

Comment: You and only you decide what to accept. Wolff has shown a way to make the effect more adjustable. My version is a plain skeleton. Know that Dissolve is not my invention, so Wolff doesn't ride on my shoulders although he mentioned he continues from where I stopped. His answer uses Photoshop's possibilities more widely.